# Strange exception using Jersey with embedded Jetty

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0, embedded-jetty

I have created an embedded Jetty application which utilizes Jersey in order to implement several RESTful services. I am using some standard code as described here in Stack Overflow as well as other websites:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Server server = new Server(8080);
      
       ServletContextHandler ctx = new ServletContextHandler(
                                      ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
      
       ctx.setContextPath("/");
      
       ServletHolder holder = ctx.addServlet(
                 "org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class", "/*");
       holder.setInitOrder(0);
      
       holder.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
                              RestfulClass.class.getCanonicalName());
      
       server.setHandler(ctx);
      
       try
       {
          server.start();
          server.join();
       }
       catch(Exception exe)
       {
          exe.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

I've used all the recommended jar files, and several other jar files that the various blogs and sites failed to mention. When running the Jetty application, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:95)

<several lines omitted for brevty>

Caused by: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:102)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:361)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:874)
... 11 more
```

It is the "UnavailableException" that I do not understand. The ServletContainer class is actually in one of the Jar files (in jersey-container-servlet-core.jar, to be precise), but for some reason it is identified as "unavailable". This is causing a class that is actually in a referenced Jar file to be "not found"!

Can anyone tell me what is causing this UnavailableException and (more importantly) how I can prevent it from being thrown?

Someone please advise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ServletHolder holder = ctx.addServlet(
         "org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class", "/*");
```

You are using a String for the class name. When doing this, you don't use the `.class` suffix. That at only when you want to get the actual `Class` object. You have two options

1. Remove the `.class` from the String

   ```
   ServletHolder holder = ctx.addServlet(
        "org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer", "/*");
   ```
2. Remove the `""` (double quotes) and just use the `Class` object<sup>1</sup>.

   ```
   ServletHolder holder = ctx.addServlet(
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
   ```

---

<sub>1 - See [`addServlet(Class, String)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.7.v20160115/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletContextHandler.html#addServlet-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-)</sub>

Comment: Greetings: This did solve the problem, though it led to another problem: I seem to be missing a class called "javax/annotation/Priority". I will try to find it, but this may turn out to be the subject of a new question...

Comment: You need the jaxax.inject jar. Go to the main jersey site and download the RI bundle if you are not using maven. You should be using all the jars that come in the bundle

Comment: I have the inject jar. I grabbed the RI bundle and am using all the jars from there. The inject jar only has one package: javax.inject. There is no javax.annotations package in any of the jars in the bundle...

Comment: [Here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/jsr250-api/1.0), I think it's in here. But I am not sure why it is needed.

Comment: [this may be a newer one](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2)

Comment: I am actually looking at the contents of the RI bundle, and that last jar I liked is in there. If you added _all_ the jars (from every directory), you shouldn't have the problem

Comment: I found the Jar(s). I needed a jar called javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar, which contained javax.annotation.Priority. I later had to add validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar in order to get the application to properly run.

Comment: You should be adding _all_ the jars. Not hand picking which ones you want to add